# I am passing msg from Child1 to Child2 via Parent.But this.prop showing values inside render() but not anywhere else in class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component,Fragment } from 'react';
import Child1 from './Child1'
import Child2 from './Child2'

class Parent extends Component{
  state={
    Parent_msg_state:""
  }
  render(){
    
    return(
      <Fragment>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        <Child1 changePstate={(msg)=>this.setState({Parent_msg_state:msg})}/>
        <Child2 msgFromChild1={this.state.Parent_msg_state}/>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Parent;

This is Parent 


#Child1#
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Child1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <table>
          <tr>John</tr>
          <tr>Cena</tr>
          <tr>12</tr>
          <tr>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={(data) => this.props.changePstate("Hi Child2")}
            >
              Send msg to child2 via Parent
            </button>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Child1;

This is Child1 

#Child2#

import React, { Component,Fragment } from 'react';


class Child2 extends Component{
    state={
        Child2_msg_State:this.props.msgFromChild1 --> Unable to map 
    }
  render(){
    return(
      <Fragment>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
          {JSON.stringify(this.props.msgFromChild1)} -->Msg is reflecting here but not in state
            <h1>{this.props.msgFromChild1}</h1>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Child2;
This is child2
```

I am passing msg from Child1 to Child2 via Parent. I have updated the Parent state from Child1 and pass that state variable as a Prop in Child2. Now I am trying to map that this.props.msgfromChild1 to Child2 state but It is not happening and it remain an empty state variable but In the render() this.props.msgfromChild1 has showing the exact passed value. I am not getting any kind of an error.

I have also tried componentdidmount to change the state but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `msgFromChild1` in props, but it's not being updated in state of child2 because the following code,

```
state={
    Child2_msg_State:this.props.msgFromChild1
}
```

Only sets the initial state of `Child2_msg_State`, it does not update the state when props change.

You were almost right when you tried to use `ComponentDidMount` but what you need is `ComponentDidUpdate`, while `ComponentDidMount` is called only during the first render of the component, `ComponentDidUpdate` function is called every time a component's data changes, in our case the value of props changes.

So, we have to update our state as props when it changes. Using the following function in `Child2` component:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Added prevProps conditional check to prevent infinite loop
    if (prevProps.msgFromChild1 !== this.props.msgFromChild1) {
      this.setState({
        Child2_msg_State: this.props.msgFromChild1
      });
    }
  }
```

In the above code, we are updating the `Child2_msg_State` whenever `Child2` component is updated using `ComponentDidUpdate()` function

Find the same from CodeSandbox below

[image: Edit dreamy-kepler-33eev]

Comment: On clicking the button it's showing an error-
×
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

even the code that u have shared having the same error

Comment: I edited the answer, and the sandbox. Please check now, had to make a `prevProps` conditional check before performing `setState`

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize your state in the `constructor`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {/*initialization*/};
  }
```

If your component still doesn't change the state, try this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.Child2_msg_State !== nextProps.msgFromChild1)
        this.setState({
            Child2_msg_State: nextProps.msgFromChild1
        });
}
```

Comment: OP's problem is not initialisation. The problem is, local state isn't updated when props are updated.

Comment: Its show an error

×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: React Docs recommends `ComponentDidUpdate()` instead of `getDerivedStateFromProps()`

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops